# model image store in firebase and use FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

how to store my model image in firebase? i want to know that how can i pass List<List<List>> in future.
Please let me know about this problem.

- for get image

  Future _getImage(String filePath) async {
  var _urlImage =
  await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath).getDownloadURL();

  return _urlImage;
  }
- add in future builder

  ```
         FutureBuilder<Model>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Model> snapshot) {
                // Checking if future is resolved or not
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  // If we got an error
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '${snapshot.error} occurred',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    );

                    // if we got our data
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    // Extracting data from snapshot object
                    final data = snapshot.data;
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(
                        data!.image.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: purpleColor),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }

                // Displaying LoadingSpinner to indicate waiting state
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },

              // Future that needs to be resolved
              // inorder to display something on the Canvas
              future: _getImage(
                allList[widget.mIndex][widget.imageIndex][index].image
              ),
            ),
  ```

  - I want to know that how can I add my model image in firebase and in futureBuilder.